# Elearning Platform technology, design and architecture

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, jakarta-ee

I got a requirement wherein we have to develop e-learning platform using Flex and J2EE.
I am new to e-learning. can someone help me to identify what are all the api required, how to start design and architecture. Requirement is to develop a course management system, an authoring tool and SCORM compliant player. authoring tool should be developed in flex/flash.
can someone help me?

Manimaran

Comment: Sounds like you need a lot more help than can be answered on StackOverflow.  I suggest looking into hiring an e-learning consultant to help you through the planning phases of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I can not afford to hire a e-learn expert.

Answer (score 2):

From a technical point, if you want to develop some Flex/J2EE enterprise application you need some technology stack.

Flex libraries/frameworks: Flex 4 SDK (core library for Flex), FlexUnit, FlexMonkey, BlazeDS, Spring BlazeDS Integration, Cairngorm 3
Flex development tools: either commercial Flash Builder from Adobe or free FlashDevelop
J2EE libraries/frameworks: Hibernate, Spring
J2EE development tools: free Eclipse, commercial IDEA
Some database: commertial Oracle, or some other free.

Then you really need someone who understand the area or try to go through some elearning sites, use some of their demos and try to understand and copy the good ideas there.

Start to draw some pictures of the architecture, write some startpoint analysis about the elearning.
Study the cairngorm 3 framework, blaze ds ....

Write some prototype deploy it and test on some real application server.